# how to use mapper for list<String> from DTO set to String from DTO

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapper

```
public class MessageRqDTO implements Serializable {

    private Long id;

    private String data;

    private String device;

    private String headers;

    private Boolean isProcessed;

    private String notification;

    private String referenceCode;

    private Boolean scheduled;

    private Boolean transactional;

    private Instant startFromTime;

    private Instant expirationTime;

    private List<String> identifiers = new ArrayList<>();

    private UserTokenDTO userToken;
}
```

first dto List identifiers

```
public class MessagetoMqDTO implements Serializable{
    private Long id;

    private String data;

    private String device;

    private String headers;

    private Boolean isProcessed;

    private String notification;

    private String referenceCode;

    private Boolean scheduled;

    private Boolean transactional;

    private Instant startFromTime;

    private Instant expirationTime;

    private String identifiers ;

    private UserTokenDTO userToken;
    private String clientToken;
}
```

second DTO
use this

```
@Mapping(target = "messageDTO", source = "messageDTO")
MessagetoMqDTO toDto(MessageRqDTO m,String identifier,String clientToken);
```

Error:

```
java: Can't map property "String identifiers" to "List<String> identifiers". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "List<String> map(String value)".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method to your mapper interface:

```
    default String mapIdentifiers(List<String> identifiers){
        String identifiersSeparator = ",";
        return identifiers.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(identifiersSeparator));
    }
```